# Anylogic: Understanding the difference between shapes, walls and visibility

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to understand how shapes, walls and visibility in annylogic work. I am designing a store with various different work stations. I use 3d shapes to denote these work stations. I then put rectangular walls around these stations to prevent agents(workers) from walking through the 3d shapes representing the stations. I want to know if the additional rectangular walls are needed or if the 3d shapes on their own can prevent agents passing through the stations. Also how does visibility work. Suppose I have a shape in the presentation layer but it is set to false in terms of visibility. Does this mean the shape has no effect on the simulation or is it still having an effect and the only thing that has changed is that we can't see it in the 3d visualisation. Same with the rectangular walls. If I build a wall around a shape and set the walls visibility to false, does that mean the walls are no longer there and are no effect on the simulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Regular agents do not avoid any type of elements (not walls, not shapes)
2. Pedestrian and Transporter type agents avoid walls.
3. Pedestrian and Transporter type agents do not avoid shapes.
4. Visibility only affects visibility and not function. So if you have a wall set to not visible, Pedestrians/transporters would still avoid it.

Comment: Just to clarify, a pedestrian can pass through 3d shapes? So then I wonder what is the point of having 3d shapes. Sorry that may sound like a stupid questions but I am new to anylogic so just trying to figure stuff out. Also if I have 3d shapes in the presentation layer but they are set to false in terms of visibility, do they impact the simulation? So I guess in my situation the best thing to do to model the different work stations would be through the use of walls, right? i.e. to avoid pedestrians walking through them?

Comment: Not a stupid question, you're just trying to understand the rules of AnyLogic. 3D shapes can be used for multiple purposes that are not obstacles... You can for example create an agent animation shape that is made of 3D shapes. Walls are used specifically as obstacles to control pedestrians' movement. So yes, 3D shapes that are not visible have no impact in your case. Yes, in your case you need to use walls. Keep in mind that the pedestrian library has limitations in the PLE version (mostly 1 hour of runtime only).

Comment: Your other less elegant solution would be to draw a network of path connecting nodes to force agents to move along those paths. In such case, your workers (if agents and not pedestrians), will follow the path. The movement will be less realistic than pedestrians, but it might meet your objective.

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:64620/help/topic/com.anylogic.help/html/markup/network.html?resultof=%22%6e%65%74%77%6f%72%6b%22%20